# TempleOS and multiple CD ROM drives?

Tags: virtualbox, cd-drive, templeos, atapi

Does TempleOS v5.03 support Multiple CD-ROM drives? For example I have on

- Secondary Master: Supplemental Disk 1
- Primary Slave: Supplemental Disk 2
- Secondary Slave: Supplemental Disk 3

Can I mount them all at the same time? When I boot, I only see `T:` listed under `DrvRep()`? I see them all listed under `ATARep()`,

[image: Screenshot of ATARep]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's currently possible, from the [Demands](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Doc/Demands.html) Terry says,

> Until super-simple block devices are available, hard disk should be placed at IDE primary master 1F0/3F6 and **CD/DVD/Blu-ray should be placed at the IDE secondary master 170/376.**  Currently, the wicked CIA plays musical chairs with controllers each time you make an install.  With tons of ugly code, I do my best.

Comment: Since SATA has pretty much been the standard for many years, can you add a "translation" of this for computers that most readers own?  If the entire discussion is relevant only to old computers, it raises questions of relevance and whether Retrocomputing might be the more appropriate site.  Also, just a serving suggestion--leave off the bottom half of the quote.  The tinfoil hat commentary does nothing to add clarity to the answer and detracts from the technical content.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm about four years late but SATA is a completely different beast then IDE that is not compatible; you can get a SATA -> IDE adapter that works via a chip, but the rules of IDE do not apply to SATA. It will also never be supported; not just because the only interested developer is now deceased (and forks like ShrineOS are discontinued) but because the creator famously said that "god told him to make the temple in 640x480 16 color" (and even before that, he wanted it to be a hobbyist OS akin to Commodore BASIC); it's safe to say he was never gonna add support.

Comment: As for the rest of your comment, it's important to understand that Terry Davis had schizophernia and it was the driving force to him making this OS (which is really best left to a VM and not actual hardware, making Retrocomputing a poor choice regardless); he believed he was making god's third temple. Say what you will about the result, but most people are curious in this because of its backstory, and not because it's a useful operating system (although some posts in this category would beg to differ, the fact that there's only 12 posts is the proof that you need).